# JDBC connection to remote MS SQLServer is failing

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am testing a sample Java code to connect to MS SQL Server database and fetch some data. **The code works fine when I execute it in the same system where SQL Server is hosted but fails to connect when I execute the same program from another system over VPN**.

Here is the error which I receive:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the
> host SQLServerHost.Domain.com, named instance myInstance failed.
> Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify
> the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking
> UDP traffic to port 1434.

In the system where SQL Server is up and running:

1. Services: *SQL Server Browser, SQL Server (myInstance) and SQL Server Agent (myInstance)* are running.
2. In *SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for myInstance*:
   a. TCP/IP is enabled.
   b. IPALL: TCP Dynamic port is set to *blank* and TCP Port set to *1433*.
   c. IP6 where the domain IP address is specified: TCP Dynamics port is set to *blank* and TCP Port is set to *1433*.
3. Added Firewall rules for inbound connection to:
   a. Allow connections to Port *1433*.
   b. Allow connections to Program *D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MyInstance\MSSQL\Binn\Sqlservr.exe*.

Here is the code sample:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class FirstExample {
 // JDBC driver name and database URL
 static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";  
 static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://SQLServerHost.Domain.COM\\myInstance;databaseName=myDatabase";

 //  Database credentials
 static final String USER = "myuser";
 static final String PASS = "mypwd";
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Connection conn = null;
 Statement stmt = null;
 try{
    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

    System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

    /*Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out" is reported at above getConnection call*/
..............
..............
}//FirstExample
```

mssql jdbc jar been used is mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar.

**EDIT 1:**
In the System where SQL Server is hosted, added Firewall rules for inbound connection to allow for UDP port 1434. However, this setting also didn't help.

**Thank You**

Comment: Correct url like :

    `static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://SQLServerHost.Domain.COM/myInstance;databaseName=myDatabase";`

Comment: What is the ip of that remote system

Comment: You need to allow udp/1434 traffic in your firewall. The SQL Browser Service listens on udp/1434 and maps your instance name (myInstance) to the actual port number on the remote system. You'll need to allow that tcp/port number in your firewall as well to get a successful connection.

Comment: Hi AlwaysLearning, I tried your suggestion but that didn't work and I get the same error. Thank You.